# Is there a word for something not feeling real but it is real?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Is there a word for something not feeling real but is real?
When you go somewhere or see a picture of someplace and it feels as if it isn’t real and for a moment you are wondering if it’s just a dream and it’s just your imagination but really it is real it just looks so amazing for example the glowing water in the Maldives and the glowing water fall in Puerto Rico.

## Examples:

#### Puerto Rico

[image: 1]

#### Maldives

[image: 2]

This is the picture I am trying to say feels this way, I am talking about how the water looks and makes me feel like that=  https://images.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.dailymail.co.uk%2Fi%2Fpix%2F2015%2F04%2F30%2F19%2F2828D3A900000578-0-image-a-1_1430420241031.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dailymail.co.uk%2Fnews%2Farticle-3063104%2FChemical-reaction-causes-ghostly-fog-sweep-Welsh-beach.html&docid=XuTLMpcaeK57YM&tbnid=2yEnOznM5l0iiM%3A&vet=1&w=962&h=645&hl=en-gb&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim

This is not the only thing I mean I also mean just anything that feels that way.I would like to use it to describe the setting of a place saying that it feels unreal yet it is real, however I would like to say that without saying it like that.

Comment: What kind of a thing is it?  You haven't told us enough.

Comment: Have changed it now is it more specific?

Comment: Describe exactly in what context you want to use the word or phrase--generally we want a sample sentence. Specify the criteria you'll use for accepting answers. Detail the research you've already done. List words or phrases you've already considered but rejected, and explain why. Provide information about the connotation, register, and part of speech you are looking for.

Comment: I accept any answer that can help me with the question, and haven’t come up with any words that could be used in the way I wish to however I can add a link to a specific photo I used for the piece of writing I need this for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Surreal**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+surreal):

having the qualities of surrealism; bizarre.

*"a surreal mix of fact and fantasy"*

**synonyms:**   unreal, bizarre, unusual, weird, strange, freakish, unearthly, uncanny, dreamlike, phantasmagorical

*"a backdrop of surreal images"*

Comment: But I would not describe the works of surrealist artists as "real but seemingly unreal". To me they have no vestige of reality at all, except in a vague metaphysical sense.

Comment: Thanks so would you call this surreal ? https://images.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2Foriginals%2F5a%2Fb8%2F62%2F5ab862790a4b8cf90df0b741c3c5f9d2.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F466263367647582520%2F&docid=Qq-J2sWEVCpb2M&tbnid=Z2F2O-MG4FUTCM%3A&vet=1&w=768&h=461&hl=en-gb&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim